# How to put Git repository inside another repository?

Tags: git

So I cloned this code from repository A, and made a subfolder B inside the code.  All my work is done in the subfolder, and I want to put the subfolder under version control, but I never want to push changes in B to repository A.  In fact I don't think I even have push access to repository A.  How can I put subfolder B into repository B?

I heard about submodules but I'm getting errors when I try to use them: (I'm in subfolder B right now)

```
user@host:~/code$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /pathtosubfolder/code/.git/

user@host:~/code$ git submodule add .
repo URL: '.' must be absolute or begin with ./|../
user@host:~/code$ git submodule add ./
fatal: could not create work tree dir ''.: No such file or directory
Clone of '/pathtosubfolder/code/' into submodule path '' failed
user@host:~/code$ git submodule status
user@host:~/code$ rm -rf .git
user@host:~/code$ git submodule init
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

Thanks!

Comment: `You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.`

Comment: If you don't want to push, then don't push.  :P  What you have is a clone -- a largely independent copy -- of A.  You can make all the changes you want to it locally, and even commit and push them elsewhere, without A ever knowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create B repository with your code
2. In your A project folder do:

   git submodule add git://repo-b-path.git codes
3. You must work with "submodule" command in your A repo